# Is it possible to change the IP address of a Javascript Paho MQTT client after Creating it?

Tags: client, mqtt, paho

I'm writing a web application in javascript where I want a single Paho.MQTT.Client to be able to disconnect from an MQTT broker, and connect it to another MQTT broker with a different IP address.

Is this possible?

Or do I have to delete my existing Paho.MQTT.Client and create a new one with a different IP address in order to switch between different MQTT brokers?

I've tried myClient._setHost("a.b.c.d"); and that returns 'Unsupported', even after a call to myClient.disconnect().

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new instance of the client to change which broker it is connected to once `connect()` has been called.

the `_setHost()` function is internal only (not listed as part of the public API) and should not be used.